# Phoenix Library not working with Android 12

Tags: android, apache-phoenix

I am devloping one app which will restart after phone reboot for that I used Phoenix Third party library it is working upto Android pie version but for higher version it is not working.

Below is a code for that.

Build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:2.0.0'
```

GlobalTool.Java

```
    public static void restartApplication(Context context) {


        Log.d("IN App restart:", "");
        ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context);


   }
```

Comment: And what answer do you expect?

Comment: @Dewerro any code changes require for Android 12?

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix/issues/47 - This github issue post might help you. Also latest version in `2.1.2` , try using that.

Comment: added Process-phoenix project in main project and added implementation ('process:phoenix') into app level build.gradle but getting error